# Words to refer to something in general

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I wrote this sentence

> To detect the boundaries of the segments, we may use **text and visual signals** as we scan the page top-down or bottom-up. In this paper, we refer to such **(features/items/elements/signals ?)** with the term anchor. **(In our terms/in this term ?)**, they are mainly textual **elements** within the page content, which serve as the starting point  of a data region  or a distinctive feature within them.

Sometimes I want to refer to something in general (like item, element...). what are the words for it in order of generality and commonness?

Comment: There are A LOT of words referring to something general. Could you narrow your search to a shorter list of perhaps 3-5 words? Or simply the most common word? Just from searching the synonym of _item_, it came up with 34 different words. Here's the link: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/item

Comment: @CipherBot I provide the paragraph to provide the context. it refers to *text and visual signals*

Comment: Just to clarify. You are asking to list these 4 words; features, items, elements and signals, in order of commonness. is that correct?

Comment: @CipherBot these or any word you offer, by general I mean, when you don't have a specific thing to say how you select a word. it seems "element" here is suitable as they are part of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graph by Google Ngrams on the commonness of the words you provided.
[image]

As you can see, the usage of *elements* is by far the most common out of the four. But as in comparison to the word *things* which may or may not fit into your context, *things* is much more used.
[image]